# How to check if a substring is present in a string which is part of an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, string, substring

So I'm adding Students (which are objects) to my arrayList and in the beginning of the code I'll let the user add as many students + studentnumbers until they enter blank. Once they entered blank my program prints out all the students and their studentnumber. Once it printed out the students and their number the user is asked to give a search term. Then the program will print out all the students which have said search term. Everything in my code works apart from comparing the search term with the strings in my `ArrayList`

This is what I came up with so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);    
    ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
        System.out.print("name: ");
        String name = reader.nextLine();
        while (!name.equals("")) {

            System.out.print("studentnumber: ");
            String studentNumber = reader.nextLine();
            students.add(new Student(name, studentNumber)); 
            System.out.print("name: ");
            name = reader.nextLine();
        }
        for (Student prs : students ) {
            System.out.println(prs);
        }

        System.out.println("Give search term: ");
        String searchTerm = reader.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Result: ");

        for (Student prs : students) {
            if (prs.contains(searchTerm)) {
                System.out.println(prs);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is how I can fix the code line

```
for (Student prs : students) {
    if (prs.contains(searchTerm)) {
        System.out.println(prs);
    }
}
```

to make it work.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: What *should* this code print, and what is it printing instead?

Comment: Expose a method in your `Student` class to return the field baed on which you have to search. And use `contains()` on it

Answer (score 1):

Modify your student class like this no need to change other code,just look it into custom contains method

```
package com.tried;

public class Student {

    String name;

    String studentNumber;

    public Student(String name2, String studentNumber) {

        this.name=name2;
        this.studentNumber=studentNumber;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getStudentNumber() {
        return studentNumber;
    }

    public void setStudentNumber(String studentNumber) {
        this.studentNumber = studentNumber;
    }

    public boolean contains(String term){
        System.out.println(this.studentNumber+"and"+this.name);
        if(this.studentNumber.contains(term) || this.name.contains(term)){

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [name=" + name + ", studentNumber=" + studentNumber + "]";
    }




}
```

Comment: This is really the beautiful and OO solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you overrode the toString method of Student class properly, change

```
for (Student prs : students) {
    if (prs.contains(searchTerm)) {
        System.out.println(prs);
}
```

with

```
for (Student prs : students) {
    if (prs.toString().contains(searchTerm)) {
        System.out.println(prs);
}
```

Comment: Yes this works. Thanks! Can you please elaborate a little on why I've to covert the values of prs to Strings? What exactly is happening to my code? Arent the values in Student already Strings?

Comment: In order to answer that question, I need to see the contains method of your Student class.